# PHP shell_exec not working with youtube-dl but the same command working fine on terminal

Tags: php, powershell, shell-exec, youtube-dl, yt-dlp

When I run the same command "youtube-dl -J [https://youtu.be/xbYw_WhrlRc"](https://youtu.be/xbYw_WhrlRc%22) in the windows terminal it works fine but in PHP it doesn't work. I am using laravel & I am not getting any errors while running the codes. But it doesn't return anything.

```
if(function_exists('shell_exec')) {
   $cmd = "youtube-dl -J https://youtu.be/xbYw_WhrlRc";
   return shell_exec($cmd);
} else {
   return "Function Not Exists";
}
```

Comment: And you're running this on the same computer as the terminal command, is that correct? Also where do you return this data to? Do you actually echo it anywhere?

Comment: Yes, running on the same machine. I am returning data just to check whether it is working or not.

Comment: Yes but are you echoing that data anywhere? Return doesn't display anything

Comment: I am using postman to test this api. Also if I do "youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 https://youtu.be/xbYw_WhrlRc" with shell_exec it doesn't download the audio in the public folder. But in terminal it works fine.

Comment: Debugging shell_exec is quite hard, replace it with the exec function and retrieve both the output and the return code.

Comment: Are you sure you execute the command in a comparable environment? Keep i mind the different process owners often involved and the different shell environments those processes use.

Comment: While using exec function I am getting an empty array output  - []